# Find Proportion of Total Where Date Is Earlier than X

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

| maturity_date | bond_face_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 | 24.76 |
| 2022-11-21 | 26.5 |
| 2023-07-15 | 34.19 |
| 2023-11-21 | 35.99 |
| 2024-07-15 | 40.7 |
| 2024-11-21 | 40.8 |

I'm looking to find the proportion of the bond portfolio maturing earlier than date X. The answer should be returned as a single value.

For example, the proportion of the portfolio maturing earlier than 2024-06-30 is (24.76 + 26.5 + 34.19 + 35.99) / (24.76 + 26.5 + 34.19 + 35.99 + 40.7 + 40.8) = 59.84%

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as(select sum(bond_face_value) sum_calc 
            from mytable 
            where maturity_date <= '2024-06-30')
select concat(round((max(t2.sum_calc)/sum(t1.bond_face_value)) * 100, 2), '%')
from mytable t1, cte t2
```

OR

```
select concat(round((select sum(bond_face_value) sum_calc 
            from mytable 
            where maturity_date <= '2024-06-30')
       /sum(bond_face_value)*100, 2), '%')
from mytable
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6378b1d7ef6757cf498fcf241cb3ce19)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CASE` expression :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN maturity_date < '2024-06-30' THEN bond_face_value ELSE 0 END) / SUM( bond_face_value)
FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code. You need to filter the required data first and then divide with sum.

```
select ((sum(bond_face_value) filter (where maturity_date<'2024-06-30'))/(sum(bond_face_value))*100 from tbl_name
```